# How does MySQL deal with connection per second, then decide to block connections?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans

I am writing a Java database program, in this program i have a loop that calls about 6 methods, in each method an connection is established to MySQL indepentantly from the other connections in order to return a boolean value,the while loop runs 20 times(row count is 20) and therefore (6*20=120) connections are made in that loop, problem is, after the 14th or the 19th iteration, i get this error from MySQL:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

Also this : `at project_2.Reserve.inLarge(Reserve.java:116)`

Where line 116 contains:

```
Statement s = c.createStatement();
```

And where c is a Connection type (i.e.MySQL Java Connection type).

every function creates a connection called c and its' own statments.

I am not expereinced in MySQL, so I expect that some would tell me that this is a terrible way to  do it and then yell at me...just kidding, thanks for help.

I also tried adding thread.sleep to delay things but it didn't work.

Comment: Showing relevant code would be helpful, such as how "every function creates a connection called c", but even before you do that, I will say just as you suspect, this is not a good way to do this sort of thing.

Comment: @rmlan thanks for reply, i found the problem, i posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was in get_conn() function i had this line twice so obviously it was a little hard on the mysql server `DriverManager.getConnection(conn_str,username,pass);`:

```
 public static Connection get_conn (){
         Connection conn=null;

        try{
            conn =(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(conn_str,username,pass);
       conn =(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(conn_str,username,pass);
    }catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }


       return conn;
    }
```